# How can i remove brackets from the output of dictionary

Tags: python

In the output the values are printed with square brackets how to remove them?

```
Test= {'Python':['classes','labs','tutorial'], 'Math': 
('classes','tutorial'), 'Java':['classes',{'labs':['corejava','adv 
java']}]}

for subject, details in Test.items(): 
     print(subject, "->", details)


print("after updating...")   

Test2 = {'Math':('classes','tutorial','labs')}
Test.update(Test2)
for subject, details in Test.items(): 
    print(subject, "->", details)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would I do it for this particular case:

```
Test= {'Python':['classes','labs','tutorial'], 'Math': 
('classes','tutorial'), 'Java':['classes',{'labs':['corejava','adv java']}]}

for subject, details in Test.items(): 
     print(subject, "->", details)


print("after updating...")   

Test2 = {'Math':('classes','tutorial','labs')}
Test.update(Test2)
for subject, details in Test.items(): 
    try:
        print(subject, "->", ' '.join(details)) 
    except TypeError:
        print(subject, "->", ''.join(details[0]),''.join(list(details[1])),' '.join(details[1]['labs']))
```

Output:

```
Python -> ['classes', 'labs', 'tutorial']
Math -> ('classes', 'tutorial')
Java -> ['classes', {'labs': ['corejava', 'adv java']}]
after updating...
Python -> classes labs tutorial
Math -> classes tutorial labs
Java -> classes labs corejava adv java
```

### HOWEVER

You are seeing the value in brackets, because that's how `lists` are displayed, and `tuples` are displayed between parenthesis. If you wish to eliminate the lists, then you can either print each value individually and append it to a string, or turn the whole list into one big string and eliminate the brackets.
In the final 3 lines I added this:

```
for subject, details in Test.items(): 
    print(subject, "->", details)
    print(type(details))
```

Which resulted in the output I talked about before:

```
Python -> ['classes', 'labs', 'tutorial']
<class 'list'>
Math -> ('classes', 'tutorial', 'labs')
<class 'tuple'>
Java -> ['classes', {'labs': ['corejava', 'adv java']}]
<class 'list'>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any brackets, you can loop through individual keys and print them. Here is one of the options

```py
Test= {'Python':['classes','labs','tutorial'], 'Math':  ('classes','tutorial'), 'Java':['classes',{'labs':['corejava','adv java']}]}

for subject, details in Test.items():
    print('\n'+ subject, "->", end=' ')
    for details in details:
        if( isinstance(details,dict)):
            for subject, details in details.items():
                print('\n'+ subject, "->", end=' ')
                if(isinstance(details,dict)):
                    for subject, details in details.items():
                        print('\n'+ subject, "->", end=' ')
                        print(' '.join(details))
                else:
                    print(' '.join(details))
        else:
            print(details, end=' ')
```

Update: Considered inner dicts

Comment: This fails for the third case

Comment: Oh I didn't notice, we can add additional conditions using type statement and if it is a dict element, then we can loop it through items again. I guess @Celius Stingher is updating the code. If not, I can write one.

Comment: You can do it and I'll upvote your answer, you can check my answer for ideas :)!

Comment: Updated code. If you don't want a new line for inner dict, you can remove new line character.

Comment: Nice use of isinstance.